# How can i find the email address of the "reports to" in MS Office Organization?

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, win32com

**Problem:** I have a list of email addresses of employees in my company. I want to store the email address of their boss/leader(called "Reports to" in Outlook Organization tab).

**Info:** I want to use Python 3.x to resolve the issue. Best would be to use win32.Dispatch('outlook.application') or similar that not require Active Directory admin intervention.

**Screenshot from outlook:**

[image]

**The solution:**

I found the solution after reading Eugene Astafiev's post below. Thanks a lot!

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
gal = outlook.Session.GetGlobalAddressList()
entries = gal.AddressEntries

recipient = outlook.CreateRecipient("name@domain.com")
recipient.Resolve()

print ("recipient:", recipient)
print ("recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager():", recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager())
print ("recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager().PrimarySmtpAddress:", recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager().PrimarySmtpAddress)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GetExchangeUserManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.getexchangeusermanager) method of the `ExchangeUser` class from the Outlook object model. The sequence of property and method calls looks in the following way:

```
Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager()
```

`ExchangeUser` is derived from the `AddressEntry` object, and is returned instead of an `AddressEntry` when the caller performs a query interface on the `AddressEntry` object.

This object provides first-class access to properties applicable to Exchange users such as `FirstName`, `JobTitle`, `LastName`, and `OfficeLocation`. You can also access other properties specific to the Exchange user that are not exposed in the object model through the `PropertyAccessor` object. Note that some of the explicit built-in properties are read-write properties. Setting these properties requires the code to be running under an appropriate Exchange administrator account; without sufficient permissions, calling the `ExchangeUser.Update` method will result in a "permission denied" error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have an instance of the `AddressEntry` object, use `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().Manager` (returns another `AddressEntry` object, be prepared to handle nulls and errors).